# Facebook PHP SDK – how do I know if $facebook->getUser() is the user I need?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is quite tricky to explain in just a few words, so let me be a bit more precise.

I have a website that optionally connects to facebook to offer more features. For these features, the site fetches some information through the graph api : basic profile + friends.

Some users connect directly with Facebook while some others connect in a more classic way with their login/password.

For those who connect with their login and password, and want to connect their account to facebook, I proceed the usual way with the php SDK. Adapted from [facebook's github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) :

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) 
{
  try 
  {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
  } 

  catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
  {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

else
{
    header('Location:'.$facebook->getLoginUrl());
}
```

The problem is, if a user connects from a friend's device, chances are that the browser is connected to his friend's facebook, and not to my user's. Or there might be no connected user to facebook at all.

Hence, $facebook->getLoginUrl() won't connect to my user's facebook, but to his friend's. It's quite annoying because it will popup the autorization dialog if his friend has never connected to my app…

Alternatively, if there was no connected user, it starts by asking to connect to one's facebook account.

In both cases, I would rather not connect to Facebook through the loginUrl and use a token (stored in database) to access the required datas. Nevertheless, these tokens last 60 days only, so each time  the user can connect through the loginUrl, it's better because it refreshes the token expiry date.

At last, my question is: is it possible to know a user's id before redirecting to the loginUrl, or to know if no user is connected to facebook at all?

Or is there any other solution that could avoid to prompt the auth dialog?

Comment: its not annoying at all it is the expected behavior.

Comment: _“is it possible to know a user's id before redirecting to the loginUrl”_ – only if they _are_ already “connected” and cookies under your domain still exist. But that doesn’t help with your user-on-a-friends-device scenario. _“or to know if no user is connected to facebook at all”_ – the SDk had a method `getLoginStatusUrl` a while back (it got you the info whether or not a user was logged in to Facebook), but that’s deprecated now.

Comment: That sucks. I just like to avoid asking for permissions while it concerns a friend's account because, as soon as it's connected, I get the facebook's user_id and I discard the informations because they are not relevant (bob's account on my website has to sync with bob's facebook account, not alice's, otherwise it's nonsense)

Comment: @lagbox I know it's the expected behaviour, but it's annoying for the user experience. I find it normal that the first time that you connect to an app you have to review the permisions it asks for, but it's like if you sync your spotify account with facebook, and when you try to connect from a friend's device, there's an auth dialog requesting permissions for you friend's facebook account, because you connect to your spotify account. It should just detect it's not the right FB account and skip the auth process before the auth dialog. I hope I'm being clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

since your using a 3rd party login system i would say your not really dealing with sensitive information. more than likely your dealing with some sort of community networking. i wouldn't worry about the issue your facing to much because if a user didnt want someone to see there sensitive information they would sign out of facebook. though a solution you could do would be to clear facebook cookies and force the website to sign them out. but your user might not like that. sooo you could do this..

```
>>clear face book cookies
>>ask login info
>>relog into facebook
```

relogging into face book might be a little tricky but im sure you can figure it out.

to finalize your question on is it possible to know a users id before redirecting to the login url, the answer is yes. just check for the facebook cookies and decode them if they are encoded.

Comment: Sure it's not really dealing with sensitive informations. Actually this issue is rather a matter of user experience. It's annoying for a user to have a prompt asking to connect to facebook or to have an auth dialog which requires permissions for a friend's account (as it's for instance a friend's computer and thus his cookies correspond to his facebook account). Regarding facebook cookies, I can't check for them as they don't belong to my domain…

Comment: The only solution would be to force facebook to log out because Facebook does not allow multi logging. forcing a user to log out of facebook may be annoying as well. if your a real pro (and i would suggest if i didnt think you could do it yourself) you could make the login page like normal and have them type in the user name and password and check the facebook cookie for the user name and compare the password with the facebook hash. just look at the cookies and try to find vulnerabilities.

Comment: @user *face palm* no you do not have direct access to 3rd party domain cookies. it takes some hacking and it can be done, iv'e done similar hacks before.

Comment: could you give a link to some ressource to do that?

Comment: Really? just create an iframe and inject the javascript for the cookies.. ?

Comment: The iframe technique works for 3rd party cookies only if you control both siteA and siteB, like you create a cookie via an iframe on siteA and read it back on siteB. Here siteA is facebook so I can't think about it… It's actually the technique used by adsites. If you have some way to do it without having an iframe in siteA, you have found a security breach. http://anantgarg.com/2012/02/18/busting-the-cookies-and-privacy-myth/

Comment: *face palm* Site A is your site, Site B is facebook. in your website make a iframe that goes to facebook then on your site outside the iframe not writing to the document directly inject the javascript that will return cookie values. if you cant do that then your injecting the javascript wrong.

Comment: Well, I might not know how to do it, but apparently, when browsing stackoverflow, I'm not the only one who says it's not possible or who doesn't know how to do it. So if you could show me a working piece of code, I might change my mind on the possibility to realize such a thing.